# Break down by month sub select statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I my query im breaking down data by 12 month, but column `'Submitted - New Business'` coming from another table. Is any chance it can also be broken down by month?

```
    SELECT      'Eldred, Rod' AS Underwriter,                   
                SUM(CASE WHEN Underwriter = 'Eldred, Rod' THEN UWReportFee ELSE 0 END) as 'UW ReportFee',
                (SUM(CASE WHEN Underwriter = 'Eldred, Rod' THEN Fees ELSE 0 END)) - SUM(CASE WHEN Underwriter = 'Eldred, Rod' THEN UWReportFee ELSE 0 END) as 'Taxes & Surcharges',
                COUNT(CASE WHEN Underwriter = 'Eldred, Rod' AND PolicyType = 'New Business' THEN QuoteControlNum  END)  as      'Submitted - New Business',
        /*SubQuery*/
                (
                SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN Underwriter = 'Eldred, Rod' AND Type = 'New Business' THEN ControlNo  END) 
                FROM        tblCalendar b  
                LEFT JOIN   ClearanceReportMetrics a ON b.MonthNum=Month(a.EffectiveDate)    
                AND b.YearNum = YEAR(a.EffectiveDate) AND CompanyLine = 'Arch Insurance Company' AND YEAR(EffectiveDate)=2016
                ) as 'Submitted - New Business' ,
        /* End of SubQuery*/

                b.MonthNum,
                b.YearNum
    FROM        tblCalendar b  
    LEFT JOIN   ProductionReportMetrics a ON b.MonthNum=Month(a.EffectiveDate)   
                AND b.YearNum = YEAR(a.EffectiveDate) AND CompanyLine = 'Arch Insurance Company' AND YEAR(EffectiveDate)=2016
                --AND a.Underwriter ='Eldred, Rod'
    WHERE       b.YearNum = 2016
    GROUP BY    --a.Underwriter,
                b.MonthName,
                b.MonthNum,
                b.YearNum
```

[image]

as you can see on a pic, every Month has the same value, is any chance to break it down somehow without usin `JOIN`  ?

Comment: use a correlated subquery to join b.month from your outer to your month(a.effectivedate)?  but you would need to alias the inner query B table differently I believe.

Comment: Thanks. But is any good example on your mind?

Comment: You need join 2 grpouped queries  or cross apply after grouping. What's wrong with join?

Comment: The data is messed up in the other table.

Comment: any example of how to do  2 grpouped queries or cross apply after grouping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try joining grouped data sets

```
    declare @uw varchar(50) ='Eldred, Rod';
    declare @year = 2016;
    declare @cn varchar(50) ='Arch Insurance Company';

    SELECT      @uw,                   
                t1.'UW ReportFee',
                t1.'Taxes & Surcharges',
                t1.'Submitted - New Business',
                t2.cnt as 'Submitted - New Business count' ,
                b.MonthNum,
                b.YearNum
    FROM        tblCalendar b  
    LEFT JOIN   ( 
                SELECT 
                Month(EffectiveDate) as Month,
                SUM( UWReportFee) as 'UW ReportFee',
                (SUM(Fees ) - SUM(UWReportFee ) as 'Taxes & Surcharges',
                COUNT(CASE WHEN PolicyType = 'New Business' THEN QuoteControlNum  END)  as 'Submitted - New Business',
                FROM ProductionReportMetrics 
                GROUP BY Month(EffectiveDate),
                WHERE YEAR(a.EffectiveDate) = @year AND CompanyLine = @cn AND Underwriter = @uw
                ) t1 ON t1.Month = b.MonthNum
    LEFT JOIN   ( 
                SELECT 
                Month(EffectiveDate) as Month,
                COUNT(ControlNo) as cnt 
                FROM ClearanceReportMetrics
                GROUP BY Month(EffectiveDate),
                WHERE YEAR(a.EffectiveDate) = @year AND CompanyLine = @cn AND Underwriter = @uw AND Type = 'New Business'
                ) t2 ON t2.Month = b.MonthNum
   WHERE       b.YearNum = 2016
```